# Find coordinates of intersection between two circles, where one circle is centered on the other

Tags: geometry, circles

I'm writing a program where an object needs to move from point A to point B. 
A and B are points on the same circle. Point B corresponds to the intersection between the circle and another circle centered on A.

The coordinates of A, and O are known. A can be anywhere on the circle.
The radii of both circles are decided by the user. 
From this, I need to calculate the coordinates of B.
The important part is that the distance between A and B is exactly as specified.

Here is a graphical representation:

[image]

Update:
I removed my incorrect implementation of the formula to avoid confusing future readers. The solution by Daniel Fischer is correct.

Comment: The correct way is `B.x = cos(alpha)*(A.x - O.x) - sin(alpha)*(A.y - O.y) + O.x;` `B.y = sin(alpha)*(A.x - O.x) + cos(alpha)*(A.y - O.y) + O.y;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $r$ be the radius of the circle with centre $A$, and $R$ the radius of the circle with centre $O$. Let $\alpha$ be the angle $BOA$.

Then $r = 2R\sin (\alpha/2)$, or $\alpha = 2\arcsin \frac{r}{2R}$, and you can obtain the coordinates of $B$ by rotating $A$ around $O$,

$$\begin{pmatrix}B_x\\B_y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\cos \alpha & -\sin \alpha\\ \sin \alpha & \cos \alpha \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}A_x - O_x\\A_y - O_y \end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}O_x \\O_y \end{pmatrix}.$$

(I have rotated clockwise, according to the picture.)

Comment: I am not getting the correct result, perhaps because I'm not implementing the formula correctly. I'll add what I'm using to the main post.